# Where is Willdfly 8.1 runtime in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, wildfly-8

The Eclipse (Kepler) Server -> Runtime environments contains WildFly 8.1 runtime but when I'm trying set up a Wildfly server runtime for webapp in Add Library -> Server Runtime it does not contains Wilfly runtime... So how set up it?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download jboss tools from **download additional server adaptors** which on the right and up of selecting Wildfly 8.1. Then you have to down load the WildFly 8.1 server in some location. after you can use that WildFly 8.1 server any time with your eclipse.